# An intrusive list of unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, pointers, ownership, intrusive-containers

I have a program that is highly multi-threaded and it contains an intrusive linked list of objects.  I need to pass off the objects in this list to several threads, but only 1 thread will ever own the object at a time, meaning that I don't need this object or the pointer to it be shared.

I wanted to create an intrusive list with a unique_ptr using boost, but from what I've read the unique_ptr would not be compatible with the Boost intrusive library as it does not have the right ownership semantics.

Per [this](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/boost_1_36_0/intrusive/using_smart_pointers.html#intrusive.using_smart_pointers.smart_pointers_requirements) the intrusive library requires it's elements (pointers) to have the same ownership semantics as a raw pointer.  So unique_ptr or even shared_ptr would not qualify.

I wondered if anyone could give me some advice on how to best implement my intrusive list then so I can safely pass its elements through several threads and know that they are being MOVED to that thread and NOT shared amongst threads?

Comment: What I don't get is why it is important for you that the *pointers* to your object are only referenced from one thread. (Which they aren't anyway, since the are at least referenced from the intrusive container *and* each each smart pointer.)

Comment: I just thought it would be better from a thread safety point of view, since if only 1 thread has a reference, there can be no thread safety problems.  It seems that obviously I did not consider the list itself...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I follow, for this to work you will need some kind of [auto-unlink hooks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/intrusive/auto_unlink_hooks.html).

Since the intrusive container does *not* own the objects it contains, you should not have any problem adding the raw pointers your unique_ptrs refer to, to the intrusive container.

If you need to be able to access the actual unique_ptr from the raw pointer in the intrusive list, something along the lines of [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) might help. (You'd need to combine your intrusive container with an intrusive unique_ptr.)

---

After thinking about it a bit it seems that there really isn't an intrusive unique_ptr variant out there, since the "intrusive" part for smart pointers usually is for the reference count, and unique_ptr like objects do not have a reference count.

Probably you would be best of using shared_ptr for this, since it already has enabled_shared_from_this.

Comment: This sounds interesting.  So I'd stick the raw pointers in my container and when I need to use them I convert them back to a unique_ptr using a type of enable_shared_from_this construct...  Could you elaborate a bit more on your ideas?